# Debian one time setup after reboot

Tags: debian, bash-script

I have a pre-configured server based on Debian with some services. I, now, need to deploy it in different networks.

Is there any solution to run a *one time* script after reboot which asks some questions about network configuration and to make this change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your script in an executable file, which, when run, as the last thing, makes itself non-executable. You may call it from /etc/rc.local, checking, before running it, whether the file is executable. If it is, fine, just run it, otherwise don't.

In your /etc/rc.local, include a statement like

```
 if [ -x /home/myname/bin/myscript.sh ]; then /home/myname/bin/myscript.sh; fi
```

Then put your commands in the file /home/myname/bin/myscript.sh, allowing it to begin as:

```
  #!/bin/sh

  START_DIR=$PWD
  SCRIPT_NAME=$0
  ......
```

and put, as the last line to be executed:

```
  chmod 644 $START_DIR/$SCRIPT_NAME
```

Make the file executable (chmod 755 myscript.sh).